# Tableau - Count the maximum number

Tags: count, max, tableau-api

I have a dataset of employees by Segment, I was trying to find by each Segment what is the maximum sales % and how many employees achieved it.

First, I have created a calculated field, Target Achievement = Actual Sales / Target Sales, which works fine. Next, I would like to find what is the maximum Target Achievement and how many employees achieved in a filtered Segment?

I have tried using WINDOWS_MAX(), which returned  the correct maximum Target Achievement, but I am not able to count the employees who have achieved the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the WINDOW_MAX in another calculation? Something like:

```
IF [TargetAchievement] = WINDOW_MAX([TargetAchievement]) THEN [EmployeeID] END
```

If that works you can count / countd that field.

An alternative, which may be more effective in this case, would be to use LOD calculations. Something along the lines of this: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/create-fixed-bins-from-a-measure-in-tableau/

For your example the FIXED may need applying within the [TargetAchievement] field; "fixing" the Actual and Target Sales.

Answer (score 1):

Create a binary calculated field 'achieved_max' as follows:

```
IF [Target Achievement] >= WINDOW_MAX([Target Achievement])
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

After that try:

1. Drag this new 'achieved_max' to Columns tab and drag Number of Records from Measures to Rows Tab.
2. Filter by Segment

Number of Records with 'achieved_max' as 1 should be the the number employees who achieved the max target in the chosen segment.

Comment: Just an FYI, for a tiny efficiency gain the above formula can be written as: 
[Target Achievement] >= WINDOW_MAX([Target Achievement])